# Can i print using FIleOutputStream on a printer

Tags: java, printing, io

Can i print using FIleOutputStream on a printer ?

*(I am targeting windows platform particularly win32)*
For example :

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("lpt1");
fos.print("testing testing testing testing...");
```

**Will these two lines be able to print on a printer ?**

If no , please suggest a method.

Comment: Gupta: *"Will these two lines be able to print on a printer ?"*  What happened when you **tried it?**

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson I haven't tried yet but was guessing if it can do ? Actually i was in a certain doubt when i read the post http://patriot.net/~tvalesky/lpt.html

Comment: Gupta: *"..but was guessing"*   For pity's sake, you could have tested this within a space of 2 minutes, 46 minutes ago!  Stop guessing & **try it!**

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson I don't have a printer right now .Will test tomorrow morning in the college lab    **(12:50 AM)**